# Why doesn't clear_output() clear what's printed to the python console in VS code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ipython

New to programming and currently working on a web scraper.  I'm trying to monitor my progress and keep my terminal clean as I go using clear_output() from IPython.display, but it doesn't appear to be clearing my output in VSCode.  Here's an example:

```
from time import sleep
from IPython.display import clear_output

x = 0
while x < 5:
    x += 1
    sleep(.2)
    print(x)
    clear_output(wait=True)
```

I'd expect it to clear the previous value of x in place of the new value, but it doesn't.  Once the program finishes, my output changes from:

```
>>>1
>>>2
>>>3
>>>4
>>>5

to:

>>>1
>>>2[2K
>>>3[2K
>>>4[2K
>>>5[2K
```

Guessing this is something from IPython, but I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I am almost 100% sure that this is the wrong approach: you **don't** want to clear the console within your code: if it's debugging information (or other), then you want to do it in the config of your text editor (like check the option "clear console before code execution" or whatever VS proposes); otherwise, if you want to make a text application that has a control on the console, use a library dedicated to that (such as curses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you're asking but you could try using the sys library:

```
from time import sleep
from sys import stdout
for i in range(0, 1000):
    stdout.write("\b")  # \b for backspace, you may need \r depends on  system
    sleep(.9)
    stdout.write("\b\b\b>>>" + str(i))
    stdout.flush()
```

for me the output is:

```
>>>1
```

then the 1 is replaced by a 2

```
>>>2
```

2 replaced by 3 etc.

I threw in a sleep so you can see what happens, as stated in the comment you may need to change the \b to a \r or some combination of both

Comment: no problem make sure you try with double, triple and 4 digit numbers. In my testing the \b didn't work as intended (the >>> got bigger with double digit numbers). \r solved this for me as you stated above.

Answer (score -2):

***clear_output()*** only works in Jupyter. Consider using **print('\n'*100)*** to clear the output in other IDEs.